# VLT Tools' "vlt export" command does not overwrite

Tags: aem

I'm working on "vlt" command 
( File Vault - [Jackrabbit FileVault](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/usage.html) comes prepackaged in AEM [VLT Tool](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/ht-vlttool.html) )

```
vlt --credentials admin:admin export -v http://localhost:4502/crx /content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/activities /Users/temp/data
```

The above command works fine and exports the Assets in "geometrixx-outdoors/activities" to **jcr_root** and **META-INF** folders. If these folders are missing, the command would even create them.

But if run the same command using a different **source** (geometrixx/portraits) and same **destination** (/Users/temp/data) like:

```
vlt --credentials admin:admin export -v http://localhost:4502/crx /content/dam/geometrixx/portraits /Users/temp/data
```

The command errors with the message **[ERROR] Not such remote file: /content/dam/geometrixx/portraits**

But if i use a different **destination folder** (/Users/temp/data/new), the same command works:

```
 vlt --credentials admin:admin export -v http://localhost:4502/crx /content/dam/geometrixx/portraits /Users/temp/data/new
```

What am i missing? Or this is how vlt export command works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ameesh Trikha's suggestions, i developed a shell script to use VLT Tools' **export** command to the same destination folder.

Every time **vlt export** command executes, **jcr_root** and **META-INF** folders are created. META-INF holds the config files and jcr_root maps to the jcr's source path. The exported files reside here.

If we use the same **destination folder** for all your exports, because of the path written in filter.xml, consecutive exports won't work. To overcome this, i'm doing the following:

- Make a copy of the filter.xml (i'm calling it as master filter) with **/content** as path. Since all content in jcr generally comes under this, so any export at any source path will work.
- Since we are planning to use the same destination folder for all our exports, delete the existing filter.xml file and replace it with the above master filter.xml

Copy of the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script is used to export the contents from AEM CRX to an external folder.
# $1 - Source path from where the files need to be copied from
# $2 - Destination path where the files need to be copied to
#
# Step 1 - Make sure the vault-cli sources are in path
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Software/vault-cli-3.1.16/bin
#
# Step 2 - vlt overwrites/creates the filter.xml with the source path. We need this to be removed as consecutive exports will not work if the path is not set to the source. To avoid this we remove the filter.xml and copy a file that has /content as the root so any export will work.
echo $'***Resetting filter.xml for the export...'
rm -f $2/META-INF/vault/filter.xml
cp -f /Users/temp/data/filter.xml $2/META-INF/vault
echo $'***Completed resetting filter.xml'
#
# Step 3
echo $'***Starting to execute vlt command...'
vlt --credentials admin:admin export -v http://localhost:4502/crx $1 $2
echo $'***Completed vlt command successfully'
```

Copy of the master filter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
  <filter root="/content">
    <exclude pattern="/content/jcr:system"/>
    <exclude pattern="/content/var/classes"/>
    <exclude pattern="^.*/rep:accessControl"/>
  </filter>
</workspaceFilter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first `vlt export` generates a `META-INF/vault/filter.xml` which restricts the content root allowing limited/pre-set path to be imported only.

If you want to import the content to same folder you will have to update the filter.xml to allow all the paths that you want to import.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the key point. It did work, but every time i'm running the export, the filter.xml is overwritten with the source path. If i can delete the filter.xml before i do the export, then it seems to work.

Comment: What you could do is to set the root path to a common parent so that filter takes care of blanket path.